# Using Spring with jsp: RequestMappings

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I am working on a pre-existing program and was wondering if someone cold help me figure out how to get redirecting working correctly.  I was able to create a "basic module" that came with some preloaded stuff.  It came with a view and controller.  What I am trying to do is create another view and controller and be able to access this second view from the first.

Here is the bean it created:

```
<beans ...>
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping"/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="@MODULE_PACKAGE@.web.controller" />
</beans>
```

And this is in the Controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "module/myfirst/myfirstLink.form")
public class MyFirstFormController {...}
```

This work wonderfully but doesnt work with a new view.

here is what I put in my new controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "module/myfirst/testLink.form")
public class TestFormController {...}
```

I cant seem to find anything else in the files provided for mapping.  I just get a routing error when I try and access the new view.

Both my Controllers are exact copies of each other except for their name.  Also, both are in the same directory.  I am invoking them both in the same way.

Comment: Are both controllers in the same xxx.web.controller package?  How do you define the methods in your TestFormController, how do you invoke them (GET, POST...) and what differences do you find between TestFormController and MyFirstFormController methods? Do the view exist? Can you post the whole routing error?

Comment: they are in the both package.  I just have one onSubmit() method in each.  They are the exact same except for the view that is returned.  They both are invoked in the same way, just by clicking on a link.  The links to the views are on the same page.  I am thinking this is a problem with my handler mappings but I dont know much about them and dont know how to change/update them.

Answer (score 0):

what is the exact exception you get? Probably the controller is found, but the view it returns is invalid.